# GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play

Tags: opencv, video, gstreamer

this is a command what I run in the terminal,`rosrun ros_exploration ros_exploration`after that, I got an unexpected error as below.it should be mentioning that the note,`GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play`probably is the key point of this problem. unfortunately, I don't know how do I fix it.

```
0:00:04.442429649  3130      0x2071c90 ERROR                    omx gstomx.c:3249:plugin_init: Failed to load configuration file: Valid key file could not be found in search dirs (searched in: /home/htf/.config:/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg:/usr/local/etc/xdg as per GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR environment variable, the xdg user config directory (or XDG_CONFIG_HOME) and the system config directory (or XDG_CONFIG_DIRS)
0:00:04.990602557  3078 0x7fd5a8002e70 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:816:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "Video"

(ros_exploration:3078): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
0:00:04.990762618  3078 0x7fd5a8002e70 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:971:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no source element for URI "/18_09_11-11:44:53-PCL.avi"
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module filesink0 reported: Could not open file "Video/18_09_11-11:44:53-PCL.avi" for writing.
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module filesink0 reported: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play
) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/htf/Downloads/opencv-2.4.13.6/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 1528
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/htf/Downloads/opencv-2.4.13.6/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1528: error: (-2) GStreamer: cannot put pipeline to play
 in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Aborted (core dumped)
```

If you have ever used GStreamer or met the relevant problems and solutions, little clues would be appreciated.

---

here is a part of relevant codes,

PCL_VideoWriter.open(FileName.toAscii().data(),CV_FOURCC('M','P','2','V'),FPS,cv::Size(640,480));
        //        MainTimer->start(viewer_thr->loop_time);

```
    if(SLAM_IMG_Capture_flag == 1)
    {
        FileName.clear();
        FileName =  "Video/"+CurrDateText+"-"+CurrTimeText+"-SLAM"+".avi";
```

---

I tried to recompile OpenCV-2.4.13. here are my commands,`cmake cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/opencv-2.4.13  -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON ..`& `make`&

```
`sudo make install`
```

. Then I got this,

```
     Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.18.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 58.12.100)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 56.14.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 5.1.100)
--       avresample:                YES (ver 1.0.1)
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 1.15.0.1)
--       video:                     YES (ver 1.15.0.1)
--       app:                       YES (ver 1.15.0.1)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 1.15.0.1)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.15.0.1)
```

however, the error is that  `error: ‘CV_CAP_FFMPEG’ was not declared in this scope` or  `error: ‘CAP_FFMPEG’ is not a member of ‘cv’` still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i see you are trying to open a video file not a gstreamer pipe. For this case using FFMPEG interface of opencv might be more useful. `VideoWriter` class has an [overload function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#a808ee7d60c58af071035a19e396bfa91) for it:

```
bool cv::VideoWriter::open  (   const String &      filename,
    int     apiPreference,
    int     fourcc,
    double      fps,
    Size    frameSize,
    bool    isColor = true 
)
```

You may use it like:

```
PCL_VideoWriter.open(FileName.toAscii().data(),CAP_FFMPEG,CV_FOURCC('M','P','2','V'),FPS,cv::Size(640,480));
    //        MainTimer->start(viewer_thr->loop_time);
```

Also, is the video in correct path i.e "Video/18_09_11-11:44:53-PCL.avi"?

Comment: I also posted the relevant codes. I have never used the GStreamer, so the question is what should I type in the terminal after installed successfully if launching GStreamer.@Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: Sorry, I confused VideoCapture and VideoWriter. Now I updated the answer. Could you try the overloaded `open` function with `CAP_FFMPEG` parameter instead of the original.

Comment: to be honest, codes related to video capturing was written by one of a classmate, So I  also not sure whether the generated video on the correct path.  I was guessing the video should be saved in home/Videos(ubuntu).@Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: if possible, could you tell me what the CAP_FFMPEG parameter should be? sorry, I got confused with all of this project.@Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: `CAP_FFMPEG` _is_ the parameter. you can use it directly, or with namespace `cv::CAP_FFMPEG`. Hopefully, you have FFMPEG installed in your system and OpenCV is compiled with FFMPEG flags turned on.

Comment: However, I am using OpenCV-2.4.13. so cv::CAP_FFMPEG is not a member of "cv" namespace.@ Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: because I am using OpenCV-2.4.13, I tried to rewrite a suitable format of cv::CAP_FFMPEG. but ‘CV_CAP_FFMPEG’ was not declared in this scope. so if possible, could you tell me what is the proper format of cv:: FFMPEG under 2.4.13? Besides, I also tried to use OpenCV-3.4.0. unfortunately, most part of this project is based on OpenCV-2.4.13. so it's very difficult for me to update a new version.

Comment: I guess it's the same in 2.4. One possibility is that you are missing FFMPEG in your OpenCv build. You might need to re-build OpenCv with FFMPEG flags enabled.

Comment: I have already followed your clues and updated the descriptions of my problem as you can see above.@Alper Kucukkomurler. thank you for your patience.

Comment: @HanJingyu could you try again after enabling avresample? You need to install `libavresample-dev` package (`sudo apt-get install libavresample-dev`)

Comment: I did followed what you said, but it doesn't make sense.@ Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: I said that because FFMPEG requires all sub-requirements to work properly. Is your initial code (without CAP_FFMPEG ) also not working?

Comment: NO, without these words,  the code could be compiled smoothly. However, when typing some commands to launch the file, I will get an unexpected error as above.@Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: here is the corresponding project posted on GitHub 
 https://github.com/TengFeiHan0/AFOA-SLAM/blob/master/ros_exploration/src/captureviewer.cpp

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem? if you have more ideas, please feel free to contact me. thanks a lot.@Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: before typing rosrun ros_exploration ros_exploration, do I need to enter some other commands related to GStreamer?just as this document said,https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html 
 @Alper Kucukkomurler

Comment: @HanJingyu sorry, I forgot this thread. From what I read recompiling OpenCv doesn't affect your results, hopefully you recompiled your application after recompiling OpenCv. I don't think other commands are necessary, we want to disable gstreamer and use FFMPEG instead.